# Azure AD B2C custom policy sample cod to customize signin verification email by sendgrid

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'd like to customize email using sendgrid to send signin verification code.
I found the sample code for signup and password reset process.

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-email-verifcation-displaycontrol/policy/SendGrid

But I don't find sample for signin process.
Does anybody know sample code, URL or any related information to customize signin verification email by sendgrid?

I tried to make a new custom policy using [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-email-verifcation-displaycontrol/policy/SendGrid) and [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-email-verifcation-displaycontrol), but it didn't work well.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no sample code, but you can send the email generated when you sign-in through SendGrid. Add a reference to the DisplayControl you created and It'll work well.

```
<ClaimsProvider>
    <DisplayName>Validate Email on Sign In</DisplayName>
    <TechnicalProfiles>
      <TechnicalProfile Id="EmailVerifyOnSignIn">
        <DisplayName>EmailVerifyOnSignIn</DisplayName>
        <!-- <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" /> -->
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
        </Metadata>
        <DisplayClaims>
          <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationSSPRControl" />
        </DisplayClaims>
      </TechnicalProfile>
    </TechnicalProfiles>
  </ClaimsProvider>
```